# Quantlib Day Count between dates

Tags: quantlib

Need some help on following items regarding functions in Qunatlib:

1. Is there any function available to calculate time between two dates with specific day count convention. For Example, I want to know time between D1 and D2 using 30/360, Act/360, etc day count convention.
2. Can we know previous and next coupon dates for bonds on particular date using schedule or some other function in Quantlib. I see schedule provides all cash flow dates but need something which gives previous and next cash flow dates.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. You can write, for instance, `Actual360().yearFraction(d1,d2)`.  Look for the `DayCounter` class at http://quantlib.org/reference for docs and the list of the supported day-count conventions.
2. You can use the `CashFlows::previousCashFlowDate` and `CashFlows::nextCashFlowDate` methods.  Again, see the link above for details.

Comment: How can 2 be implemented in python? Sorry but weak with that conversion.

Comment: Sorry, those methods are not exported to Python.  You can request them by opening an issue at https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response...created https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues/100

Comment: On closer look there is one more variant of above functions qlSchedulePreviousDate and qlScheduleNextDate. I guess these methods are also not exported to Python?

Comment: Right.  You can add them to the issue.